# How has Microsoft Word's 2018 logo improved over its 2013 logo?

Tags: logo

In November 2018, Microsoft revealed a suite of new logos for the Microsoft Office family of software. Some examples are provided [here](https://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2018/11/30/microsofts-new-office-logos-are-a-beautiful-glimpse-of-the-future/).

I feel that Microsoft Word's [2013 logo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Microsoft_Word_logo.png) is familiar, in-fashion, simple, and well-accepted. I feel there is something I am not getting with Word's newer [2018 logo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Microsoft_Office_Word_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg) and the logo change.

1. Is the new logo an improvement? How so?
2. From a graphic design perspective, was it needed?

Comment: Same question could be asked about the icons and logos that came before

Comment: .. they couldn't simply use a colored rounded rectangle with the first character of the application, Adobe would sue. So they *had* to throw in something else. `:)` - Personally, I think all the "letter in a colored box" logos are merely lazy design. They work, but they're lazy.

Comment: @Scott I never considered that! Thanks for the insight! Is this why the new logo is offset?

Comment: @joojaa Sure, I could be curious about the previous logos, but I wanted the question to be relevant.

Comment: @Scott true that, but then the na,mes of the software are also very lazy.

Comment: @joojaa What do you think are some better names? Curious about your thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## From Flat to Fluid

The main improvement is the **fluidity** in the design, in my opinion a perfect adaptation of *Microsoft Fluid Design* to the icons of its own applications.

While the old logo is 100% flat design, the new one could be flat 2.0 if it were simply this logo, by the shadows and gradients addition:

[image: logos]

But it's not just that, the new logos are designed in the space, allowing a more dynamic and adaptable use, very representative words of our current digital and *Cross-platform* world.

It's not a flat element as in the typical icons, but its design based on **modules** allows a wide range of interpretations favoring its adaptability such as:

- Different perspectives
- Multiple shadows types, by position and graphic representation
- 3D thicknesses that appear and disappear or change according to the position in the space
- Brightness, yes or no
- Elements dismemberment

[image]

Conceptually pursues the idea of objects built from independent pieces, such as a Lego, something that not only points to a proximity to the receiver but also invites to use these same pieces to create their own adaptation. By the way, this is clearly shown in the video presentation.

[image]

While the typical application icon is the one shown without any alternative other than to look for a new adapted graphic, these icons offer all the possibilities without hardly altering the design.

[image: lego pieces]

Personally I'm not a big fan of MS products, but I see in these icons an excellent work, at a formal and conceptual level. One step ahead in what refers to icon design.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize a design based on modules was that useful.

Comment: I like them too. Stunning work.